# Compiling/ Linking SoftFloat library using mips-linux-gnu-gcc

Tags: linker, floating-point, static-libraries, mips, llvm-gcc

I am trying to compile and link a small C benchmark with floating-point operations for a MIPS target. The floating-point emulation library used with the benchmark is the SoftFloat. http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html

The MIPS compiler is an LLVM retargetted MIPS compiler release by MIPS Technologies: http://www.imgtec.com/mips/developers/clang-llvm.asp

Compilation is successful with the main program and also the library files. However, during linking, an error is thrown:

```
softfloat-macros:70: undefined reference to `__ucmpdi2'
```

In my opinion, the SoftFloat library is already a comprehensive library of functions which does not require me to write any new ones. However, my conclusion may be inaccurate due to my limited knowledge in compiling and linking libraries.

My main questions are:

- Can the SoftFloat library be incomplete for my target and do I need to write the missing function of `__ucmpdi2`? Or is there something else that I am missing?
- Am I compiling or linking the SoftFloat library incorrectly?

Below is an excerpt of my Makefile. I hope someone can help point out in case there is something wrong.

```
FILENAME = dfadd
MARCH = -mips1
MIPSGCC = mips-linux-gnu-gcc
MIPSLD = mips-linux-gnu-ld
CFLAGS = -Wall -c -g -msoft-float -mno-abicalls -I. $(MARCH)

mips: softfloat-macros softfloat-specialize milieu.h softfloat.h SPARC-GCC.h softfloat.c dfadd.c 
    $(MIPSGCC) -$(OPT) $(CFLAGS) $(FILENAME).c
    $(MIPSAS) -o boot.o boot.asm
    $(MIPSLD) -Ttext 0 -eentry -Map $(FILENAME).map -s -N -o $(FILENAME).elf boot.o $(FILENAME).o
```

The commands executed and the error is thrown at linker stage:

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -O0 -Wall -c -g -msoft-float -mno-abicalls -I. -mips1 dfadd.c
mips-linux-gnu-as -o boot.o boot.asm
mips-linux-gnu-ld -Ttext 0 -eentry -Map dfadd.map -s -N -o dfadd.elf boot.o dfadd.o
dfadd.o: In function `shift64RightJamming':
/home/jon/Work/bennchmark/dfadd/softfloat-macros:70: undefined reference to `__ucmpdi2'
make: *** [mips] Error 1
```

Comment: Please provide the final command used to compile and link your program, when the warning is issued.

Comment: Yes, I have edited to question to include the commands executed and the error. Thanks for pointing that out.